# Kotlin idiomatic way for passing a class to a function

Tags: kotlin

I have a method which calls an object methods that wants a callback object as parameter.
The callback object has to have 2 methods defined, onEvent1() and onEvent2().

One way is to do everything inline, but the result is that it's super-nested and becomes unreadable

```
myObj.method1(object : baseType {
     override fun onEvent1() {
               10 lines of nested code
     }
     override fun onEvent2() {
                more nested code
     }
)
```

I found it very unreadable given that a method is more 10 lines.

What is the best way to do this in Kotlin?

The only non-kotlin idiomatic way I know is to declare a class and pass an object of it, maybe inner class.

```
void mymethod() {
    class Obj : baseType {
              override fun onEvent1() {....}
              override fun onEvent2() {....}
    }
    
    val obj : Obj
    myObj.method1(obj)
}
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: Do you have to define the callback behaviour inside your `mymethod()`? Why can't you create an implementation of `baseType` (a new top-level class) that has all the callback behaviour you need, then pass an instance of it with `myObj.method1(Callback())`?

Comment: If the object of `baseType` does not have any backward reference to `mymethod()`, you can make it a singleton in class.

Answer (score 3):

What if you used two lambdas for the two callbacks? The type of the lambda would be the type for the callback function: in your example `() -> Unit`, for a function that takes no arguments and returns a `Unit` result. First we make a new method that takes the two callbacks and wraps them up into a single object:

```kotlin
fun myMethod(callback1: () -> Unit, callback2: () -> Unit) {
    myObj.method1(object : baseType {
        override fun onEvent1() { callback1() }
        override fun onEvent2() { callback2() }
    })
}
```

Then we can call the new method like this:

```kotlin
myMethod(
    callback1 = { ... },
    callback2 = { ... }
)
```

It's a little more succinct than declaring a new object each time. Another benefit is that we can define the callbacks separately before passing them into the function:

```kotlin
val callback1 = { ... }
val callback2 = { ... }
myMethod(callback1, callback2)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could define a helper class that implements the callback type, and accepts the two callback functions (as you suggested):

```
class Callback(
    private val callback1: () -> Unit,
    private val callback2: () -> Unit
) : baseType {
    override fun onEvent1() = callback1()
    override fun onEvent2() = callback2()
}
```

Then write an extension function to wrap-up the use of the helper class:

```
fun MyObj.method1(callback1: () -> Unit, callback2: () -> Unit) =
    method1(Callback(callback1, callback2))
```

Then you can call it like this:

```
myObj.method1({ println("This is callback1") }, { println("This is callback2") })
```

---

Alternatively, you could just create an implementation of the callback class:

```
class Callback : baseType {
    override fun onEvent1() {
        // 10 lines of nested code
    }
    override fun onEvent2() {
        // more nested code
    }
}
```

And pass an instance of it to `method1`:

```
myObj.method1(Callback())
```